# return const std::string*& from a std::string *tab[11]

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reference, constants

I have got an array of string in my class:

```
class A
{
   string*          tab[11];
   const string*&   getTab();
}
```

I am filling it with

> const string &str

My first think was to just do:

```
return tab;
```

But G++ tells me:

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘const string*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::string**'

What did I do wrong ?

And what should I return ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your return type is a reference to a pointer. You're returning an array of pointers, which is then decayed into a pointer to a pointer. What do you actually *want* to return?

Comment: The constant reference of the array of pointers

Comment: You have an array of pointers to string, not an array of strings like you state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string*&` is a reference to a pointer to a string.
But you woud like to return a reference to an *array* of pointers to string.
So the type you should return is `string**&` (and it can be const, of course).

Another solution would be to instead of a raw array, use the type `std::array<class T, std::size_t N>`, that way your syntax would be more clear:

```
class A
{
    std::array<string*, 11> tab;
    const std::array<string*, 11>& getTab();
}
```

`std::array` is a very lightweight wrapper for a raw c-array, so using it involves almost no performance overhead.

Comment: lucky op didn't type ‘string*& const` which would be a const reference to the first string

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to declare a suitable typedef:

```
class A
{
   typedef string Table[11];
   Table     tab;
   Table&    getTab();
};
```